# Slide divs with arrow up and down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that may contain multiple children divs.

I want to slide verticaly the inner divs when they are more than 5.

HTML and CSS:

```css
.category_sibe {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  background-color: rgba(126, 7, 209, 0.7);
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}

.category_parc {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  background-color: rgba(156, 72, 4, 0.7);
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}

.category_daya {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  background-color: rgba(7, 116, 209, 0.7);
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}

.category_faune {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  background-color: rgba(252, 154, 0, 0.7);
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}

.category_biotope {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  background-color: rgba(31, 180, 7, 0.7);
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="category">
  <div class="col-12 category_sibe" data-tooltip="SIBES" id="idSibe">

  </div>
  <div class="col-12 category_parc" data-tooltip="Parcs nationaux" id="idParc">

  </div>
  <div class="col-12 category_daya" data-tooltip="Dayas" id="idDaya">

  </div>
  <div class="col-12 category_faune" data-tooltip="Faune" id="idFaune">

  </div>
  <div class="col-12 category_daya" data-tooltip="Dayas" id="idDaya">

  </div>
  <div class="col-12 category_biotope" data-tooltip="Biotope" id="idBtp">

  </div>

</div>
```

Here is my codepen demo to better see how it looks :

https://codepen.io/zakigates-the-decoder/pen/XWdQvjr?editors=1100

Is there any way to have such a result? I tried swiper but did not work for me.

Comment: What `scroll with arrow up and down` do you need?

Comment: Being able to scroll verticaly

Comment: But I see normal vertical scrollbar in my browser and I can scroll vertically... Can you show us on some example or image what scrollbar do you need?

Comment: I meant creating a vertical slide on the parent Div when the children are more than 5. I edited my question.

Comment: You can set `overflow-y: scroll;` on parent div and set `height` to it equal to the height of 5 items... Is that enough?